# C deleting char in string

Tags: c, char, c-strings, function-definition, function-declaration

Now I'm using this code to delete some char in a string.

```
void eliminate(char *str, char ch){
    for(; *str != '\0';str++){
        if(*str == ch){
            strcpy(str, str+1);
            str--;
        }
    }
}
```

In the char *str there are some strings like

`"sll     $6, $5, 16"`

After deleting "$", the string looks like this.

`"sll     6, 5, 16"`

But after deleting ",", the string became very strange.

`"sll     6 5 6"`

Is there any problem with the code above? And also, it only happens in Linux and online GDB. VS code in my window laptop eliminates the targeted char very well.

Comment: The behavior of [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) isn't defined for overlapping memory areas. Use [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) instead (but then you have to remember to copy the ending null-terminator as well).

Comment: So why don't you use `gdb` and tell what is going on with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments `strcpy()` is not safe when coping data with overlapping memory blocks. `memmove(dst, src, len)` is the alternative which uses an auxiliary buffer in case of `src` & `dst` memory overlaps.

You can simply skip the character to eliminate in a loop:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void drop_char (char *str, char ch) {
    if (!str) return;

    for(char* cp = str; 1 ; ) {
        if(*cp != ch)
            *str++ = *cp;
        if ('\0' == *cp++)
            break;
    }
}

int main () {
    char str [] = "sll     $6, $5, 16";
    printf ("Original   : [%s]", str);

    drop_char(str, '$');
    printf ("\nDropping $ : [%s]", str);

    drop_char(str, ',');
    printf ("\nDropping , : [%s]", str);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using explicit pointer math, we can use two indices as we iterate over the input string. `i` is an index with increments on each iteration, and `j` which only increments when the target character is *not* found.

```
void drop_char(char *str, char ch) {
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;    

    for (; str[i]; ++i) {
        if (str[i] != ch) 
            str[j++] = str[i];
    }

    str[j] = '\0';
}
```

If we have the string `char test[] = "hello"` and call `drop_char(test, 'l')` the process looks like:

```
i = 0, j = 0
char: 'h'
'h' != 'l'
test[0] = 'h'

i = 1, j = 1
char: 'e'
'e' != 'l'
test[1] = 'e'

i = 2, j = 2
char: 'l'
'l' == 'l'

i = 3, j = 2
char: 'l'
'l' == 'l'

i = 4, j = 2
char: 'o'
'o' != 'l'
test[2] = 'o'

i = 5, j = 3
test[3] = '\0'
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters using the function `strcpy` for overlapping strings as in this statement

```
strcpy(str, str+1);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (7.23.2.3 The strcpy function)

> 2 The strcpy function copies the string pointed to by s2 (including
> the terminating null character) into the array pointed to by s1. **If
> copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
> undefined.**

This statement

```
str--;
```

also can invoke undefined behavior when the deleted character is the first character of the string.

Some remarks about the function declaration.

Such a function should follow the general convention of C standard string functions and return pointer to the result string.

Another general convention is that such functions do not check whether the passed pointer is equal to `NULL`. It is the responsibility of the user of the function to pass a valid pointer to a string.

Also if the user will pass `'\0'` as the character to be deleted then the function shall do nothing with the source string and just return it.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the function can be declared and defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * eliminate( char *s, char c )
{
    if ( c != '\0' )
    {
        char *src = s, *dsn = s;

        do
        {
            if ( *src != c )
            {
                if ( dsn != src ) *dsn = *src;
                ++dsn;
            }
        } while ( *src++ );
    }

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "sll     $6, $5, 16";

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", eliminate( s, '$') );
}
```

The program output is

```
"sll     6, 5, 16"
```